# Windows 7 shortcut for services and different services view in windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-services

1. What is the shortcut for services in Windows 7?
2. I can get to services in two ways:

   a. Start Task manager > click on services tab
   b. Windows Explorer - Right click on 'Computer' - 'Manage' - 'Services and applications' - 'Services'

   With Option b I can start and stop the services, but with Option a - I cannot

   So what is the difference between the two? Are there shortcuts for Option b?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Option1, you can start/stop services by doing right click on each service.

To create shortcut for services,

- RightClick on Desktop -> New -> Choose Shortcut.
- Type "services.msc"
- Click Next and click Finish.

Other way is, press "Win+R" and type "services.msc".

To permanently disable services,

- Press "Win+R".
- Type "msconfig". Go to Services tab.
- Uncheck the service that you want to disable.Click "Apply" and "OK".

You may want to restart your computer to take effect.

Comment: Press "Win+R" type: services.msc enter